# repo init stop always check latest repo

Tags: repo

Is it possible to stop verify/download newer repo from internet, such as

```
test $  repo init -u git@1.1.1.1/test/iot_manifest.git
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
Get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
remote: Counting objects: 1, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (36/36)
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, the `repo` installed on your computer (the one in your `$PATH`) is not the full version of `repo` it is only a launcher.

From the `repo` documentation on [source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading#installing-repo):

> Repo comes in two parts: One is a launcher script you install, and it communicates with the second part, the full Repo tool included in a source code checkout.

When you run `repo init` for the first time it gets the full repo and store it in the `.repo/repo` directory. Every time you'll run `repo init` again in a brand new repository, the full `repo` will be downloaded again in `.repo/repo`.

One thing though you can stop getting the clone.bundle line with `repo init --no-clone-bundle`

---

**Get repo from your own computer (without internet)**

You can use a local version of repo, you need the internet at least to get the [git-repo code](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo) once. After that you can use this version stored locally in place of the remote ones on Google server.

```
cd workspace
git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
mkdir repo_init_no_internet && cd repo_init_no_internet
repo init --repo-url=/home/<user>/workspace/git-repo
```

Comment: thanks your comment.
However, how to call all **repo init**  at internet limited case.